# Moving my godaddy wordpress site to desktop machine

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog site hosted on WordPress 4.2.2. And I have taken the contents and database backup. (Using Ready!Backup tool).

I don't need that blog over Internet anymore, so I am planing to abandon GoDaddy hosting, but continue using it on Local network. If I need to setup Wordpress on a local desktop machine (for intranet access) instead, what should I do ? . I am not familiar with web programming much.

Some tips or ideas will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: By the way I never modified the wordpress code provided by godaddy hosting. I just used their wordpress service as is.

Comment: Which OS is installed on your PC?

Comment: I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux 12.04.

Comment: Well the question is too general fit in one answer. First install and configure XAMPP for Windows, and LAMP for Ubuntu. After you finish with it, you're will have more specific question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

1) Install WAMP on your Windows machine or LAMP on your Linux machine

2) Log into your GoDaddy control panel and export a copy of the database

3) Import this into MYSQL on your WAMP/LAMP box

4) Use the GoDaddy file manager to pull a copy of the file system down on to your local machine

5) Create a new host in WAMP/LAMP pointing at the folder where you have the file system stored

6) Change wp-config.php to point at the MYSQL installation on the local machine (it will be different from that of the staging server)

7) Use WP_SITEURL and WP_CONTENT_URL to match the hostname to the one that you have chosen for your local install (or perform a search/replace on the database using the [Search and Replace tool for Wordpress Databases](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/))

8) Post a follow up here if you get stuck and I'll try and advise you...